# Android recoder voice and it catch a java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, r.java-file, web-mediarecorder

I want to recorder voice，and mix the mp3 file 
but it could not find the file

I had add the permission by  uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".

that is my code

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + Global.gContext.getResources().getString(R.string.PATH)+ File.separator + "Luyin");
if(!f.exists()){
    f.mkdir();
}
String voiceName = f + File.separator;
String sound = Global.UserNumber+"-"+System.nanoTime()+"";
List<String> soundList = new ArrayList<String>();
private void stop() {
            mRecorder.stop();
            heBingMp3();
            File f = new File(voiceName+sound+".mp3");
            if(!f.exists()){
                Global.show("请先录制声音");
                return;
            }
            wancheng = true;
            alertDialog.setMessage("正在合成，请稍后……");
            alertDialog.show();
            new DecodeAudioTask(voiceName+sound+".mp3").execute(); 
}
public void heBingMp3(){
            File f=new File(voiceName+sound+".mp3");
            for(int i=0;i<soundList.size();i++){  
                try {
                    File file=new File(soundList.get(i));
                    FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(file);
                    FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(f,true);
                    byte bs[]=new byte[1024*4];
                    int len=0;

                    while((len=in.read(bs))!=-1){
                        out.write(bs,0,len);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                    file.delete();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
}
try {
mRecorder = new MP3Recorder(new 
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),voiceName+ File.separator+"temp"+ 
File.separator + sound + soundNum+".mp3"));
mRecorder.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

soundList.add(voiceName+File.separator+"temp"+File.separator+sound+soundNum+".mp 
   3");

Comment: `W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/a___yumeng/Luyin/temp/639471-51794926991800.mp3 (No such file or directory)
 W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
 W/System.err:     at com.yumeng.activity.LuzhiActivity.heBingMp3(LuzhiActivity.java:183)
 W/System.err:     at com.yumeng.activity.LuzhiActivity.stop(LuzhiActivity.java:143)
 W/System.err:     at com.yumeng.activity.LuzhiActivity.onClick(LuzhiActivity.java:238)
`

Comment: it is my error log